# How can I view debug log flask App on IIS?

Tags: python, flask, iis

I setup a simple flask App on IIS and that work perfectly (run with wfastcgi).

app.py file:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/') def hello_world():
return 'Hello World!'
 if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True )
```

When I run with CMD I can view debug log  as shown as

[image]

But when run with IIS cant see any debug log.
How can I view this debug logs (error debug log) on IIS when App run with IIS like up?

When my app have error I see this page:
[image]

Comment: I can’t judge what went wrong just by relying on the error page. I need more detailed error information to solve the problem. You can check the event viewer or use F12 to check if there is any error information in the console.

Comment: @samwu in console write error exact above error image. my real app have many number line  and many functions. that work perfect  on local but  not on IIS .

Comment: To check whether there are related error messages in the Event Viewer, or you can use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) to get the error information.